# Flutter: How to pass pointer events to widgets behind after using the pointer events

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a widget that receives hit testing and then runs the corresponding methods. The hit test is then passed to the widgets behind the top widget.

A use case would be when there is a modal open with a transparent barrier and a user would want to click a button. The user would have to double click, the first time to dismiss the modal and the other to click the button. I don't know if this makes sense.

Is there an existing widget or plugin for this? If not how might approach this problem?